# How to pass a variable within Find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Not sure exactly how to do this and having issues finding references or help online. So far I know this much

```
def ItemName (self):
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text()')
```

The variable I am trying to include in this is

```
def Item (self):   
    Item_Name = self.lineEdit_10.setText()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DeanFenster I want the the browser to look the webpage for the Item name. The Item name should be assigned to the variable Item_Name already so i want to pass the variable that holds whatever the name is set to.

Comment: So from what I understand, all you need is a format string in `find_element_by_xpath`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DeanFenster I am very new to python so i have not but i will give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ItemName (self):
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text()')
```

Maybe you're looking for something like

```
def ItemName(self,name):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text({})'.format(name))
```

You'll be able to pass the name where the **{ }** (curly brackets are) and find it this way.